# Reminder on Google Home on Actions on Google

Tags: actions-on-google

Is it possible for a Google Action to set a reminder for Google Home? For example, I want my Action to enable the user to get a reminder when an item they want is back in stock. Ideally this reminder would hit all of their surfaces. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not, currently. [As it says in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications):

> Note: Push notifications aren't currently supported on voice-activated speakers.